# Making a list of an dynamic apex:OutputText

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I have a code in a my VF page like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Plan__c.Object__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>
```

The Object__c is type of Formula(Text) type. It returns me some 2 or 3 or 4 sentences(text) based on a condition. I would like to put these sentences in a bullet format. I tried to put it in list tag but it did not work:

```
<li><apex:outputText value="{!Plan__c.Object__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></li>
```

Since I do not know how many sentences Object__c returns at a time, how can I show each sentence as a list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the sentences on the controller and return a list and then use apex:datalist on your visualforce page to render a list of items.